# If the field is not entered, how to make it not filtered in django

Tags: django

I am creating a lookup field and would like to know how do I do so that if a field is not entered it does not appear in the address bar even if its value is null.

```
http://localhost:8000/pesquisa/?prova=
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000/pesquisa/
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    provas = Prova.objects.all().order_by('idProva')
    questoes = Questao.objects.filter().order_by('idProva')
    categorias = Categoria.objects.all().order_by('nomeCategoria')
    form = QuestaoProvaForm()
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html',{'categorias':categorias,'questoes':questoes,'provas':provas,'form':form})
def pesquisa(request):
    template_name = 'polls/pesquisa.html'
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    prova = request.GET.get('prova', '')
    questao = request.GET.get('questao', '')
    categoria = request.GET.get('categoria', '')
    results = Questao.objects.filter(idProva=prova)
    return render(request, template_name, {'results': results,'prova':prova,'questao':questao,'questoes':questoes})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a django only solution, but you can always do this with client-side javascript:

```
var remove_null_values = ($this) => {
  if (!$this) {
    $this = this;
  }
  $($this).find('input', 'select').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === '') {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
}
$('#formId').submit(function() {
  remove_null_values(this);
});
```

Comment: @MurilodeJesus did you replace `formId` with the id of your form?

Comment: Yes. I ended up using several ifs in views.py and it worked. Thanks